# Click on element that contains a specific alt tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I currently have the following code:

```
<div class="c-form-field c-form-field--radio SelectStyle col">
<label for="input_radio_style_17" aria-hidden="false" class="">
<span class="c-form-label-content">
<span class="c-image product c-image--square">
<span class="LazyLoad is-visible">
<img src="https://images.example.com/23434234.jpg" alt="Green picture frame" id="I0065001">
</span>
</span>
</span>
</label>
<input name="style" aria-labelledby="styleI0065001" id="input_radio_style_17" type="radio" required="" value="17"></div>
```

I have about 20 of these on the page sometimes that number changes, what I need to do is to loop over each and find the one that contains a specific alt tag and then click on it.
In the above example I would need to loop through a bunch and find the one that contains `alt="Green picture frame"` and then click on it.

To start I would loop through each element with SelectStyle like so.

```
const imgs = await page.$$eval('.SelectStyle', imgs => imgs.map{
    return (img => img.getAttribute('alt'))
});
```

From here I'm kind of stuck, how would I return the element which matches and then click on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that with a [CSS attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

```
const imgs = await page.$$('.SelectStyle img[alt="Green picture frame"]');
```

Comment: I got this error: (node:55234) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Expected to get |string| or |function| as the first argument, but got "undefined" instead.  any idea why? @hardkoded

Comment: So sorry @FabricioG it should have been `$$` instead of `$$eval``